# Exceptions while using mutex and condition_variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, condition-variable

I'm writing a program to read data from .txt file and using it in output .txt file. I'm using two threads; The first thread is for reading the data from the .txt file, and the second one is for writing it in the output file. I'm a beginner in the programming with mutex and condition_variable and for somehow my program handles exceptions... The exception is

```
abort() has been called.
```

These are the two threads methods:

```
void MessagesSender::readsData()
{
    ifstream data;
    data.open("data.txt");
    string buffer;
    bool toEmpty = false;
    std::unique_lock<mutex> locker(mtx, std::defer_lock);
    if (data.is_open())
    {
        while (std::getline(data, buffer)) //reads line to the buffer.
        {
            locker.lock();
            this->messages.push(buffer); //push the message to the queue.
            locker.unlock();
            cond.notify_one();
        }
        data.close();
        toEmpty = true;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error opening file... " << endl;
    }
    if (toEmpty) //empty the data file.
    {
        ofstream emptyFile; 
        emptyFile.open("data.txt", ofstream::out | ofstream::trunc);
        emptyFile.close();
    }
}

void MessagesSender::sendsData()
{
    ofstream output;
    output.open("output.txt");
    string tempString;
    string tempMessage;

    if (output.is_open())
    {
        std::unique_lock<mutex> locker(mtx, std::defer_lock);
        locker.lock();
        cond.wait(locker);
        while (!(this->messages.empty()))
        {
            tempMessage = this->messages.front();
            this->messages.pop();
            locker.unlock();
            for (std::vector<string>::iterator it = this->userNames.begin(); it != this->userNames.end(); ++it)
            {
                tempString = *it;
                tempString += ": ";
                tempString += tempMessage;
                tempString += "\n";
                output << tempString;
            }
        }
        output.close();
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Error opening file... " << endl;
    }
}
```

Why is the program handling exception?

Comment: Have you identified the offending line with your debugger?

Comment: "abort() has been called" is not an exception. If an exception was thrown and not caught, you got a more detailed message that includes the type of the exception.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I can't because the work with the threads is very unstable...

Comment: @I.Klein _"because the work with the threads is very unstable"_ Huh??

Comment: @I.Klein I don't understand what you mean. Most debuggers will be able to break on `abort`, providing you with a nice call stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible error is that you are repeatedly unlocking the `mutex` in your `while`-loop, even though the mutex is not locked:

```
if (output.is_open())
    {
        std::unique_lock<mutex> locker(mtx, std::defer_lock);
        locker.lock();
        cond.wait(locker);
        while (!(this->messages.empty()))
        {
            tempMessage = this->messages.front();
            this->messages.pop();
            // if multiple messages are in the queue, you unlock multiple times 
            // even though the mutex is not locked
            locker.unlock();   
            for (std::vector<string>::iterator it = this->userNames.begin(); it != this->userNames.end(); ++it)
            {
                tempString = *it;
                tempString += ": ";
                tempString += tempMessage;
                tempString += "\n";
                output << tempString;
            }
        }
        output.close();
    }
```

According to [unique_lock::unlock](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/unique_lock/unlock) this throws a `std::system_error`